# ConfirmDialog add-on in customcomponent?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I did download ConfirmDialog add-on. Now, I'm trying create a confirmdialong in my customcomponent, but I guess that doesn't work with this ui.

```
public class Customer extends CustomComponent implements Button.ClickListener{
    private Button btnSave;
    private VerticalLayout vLayout;

    public Customer(){
        vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        setCompositionRoot(vLayout);
        btnSave = new Button("Save");
        btnSave.addClickListener(this);
        vLayout.addComponent(btnSave);
    }

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        if(event.getButton() == btnSave){
            save();    
        } 
    }

    /** save informations if ConfirmDialog return true */
    private void save(){
        ConfirmDialog.show(this, "Please Confirm:", "Are you really sure?",
            "I am", "Not quite", new ConfirmDialog.Listener() {
                public void onClose(ConfirmDialog dialog) {
                    if (dialog.isConfirmed()) {
                        System.out.println(dialog.isConfirmed());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(dialog.isConfirmed());                       }
                }
            });
    }

}
```

when I create ConfirmDialog and pass my CustomComponent as Ui(this) does not accept. I tryed pass null, but does not work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is solved. I did use UI.getCurrent() and works.

```
/** save informations if ConfirmDialog return true */
private void save(){
    ConfirmDialog.show(UI.getCurrent(), "Please Confirm:", "Are you really sure?",
        "I am", "Not quite", new ConfirmDialog.Listener() {
            public void onClose(ConfirmDialog dialog) {
                if (dialog.isConfirmed()) {
                    System.out.println(dialog.isConfirmed());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(dialog.isConfirmed());                       }
            }
        });
}
```